# why the probability of an increasing iid sequence is 1/n!?

Tags: probability

Drawing a series iid sample from a given probaility distribution, the probability of an increasing sequence is $P(x_1<x_2<\cdots<x_n)=\frac{1}{n!}$.

How can I drive this conclusion?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Hint: say you get $n$ continuous values, which are pairwise unequal with probability $1$. How many orders could they be in? How many would be in order?

Answer (score 0):

After some thinking of three samples, I got the derivation.

Suppose there are 3 iid samples ($X,Y,Z$ ),the probaility of $P(X<Y<Z)$ is:

$$
\begin{aligned}
P(X<Y<Z) &= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_x^\infty\int_y^\infty p(x)p(y)p(z)dxdydz\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_x^\infty p(x)p(y)(1-F(y)) dxdy \quad (\text{think CDF } F(X) = P(X\le x)\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}p(x)\int_x^\infty p(y)(1-F(y))dxdy \\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}p(x)\int_x^\infty (1-F(y))dxdF(y)\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}p(x)\int_x^\infty -t dxdt \quad \text{Let } t= 1- F(y)\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}p(x) \frac{-t^2}{2}\mid^\infty_x dx\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}p(x) \frac{(1-F(x))^2}{2} dx\\
& = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{(1-F(x))^2}{2}dF(x)\\
& = \int_{1}^{0} -\frac{t^2}{2} dt \\
& = -\frac{t^3}{2\times 3}\mid^0_1 \\
& = \frac{1}{6}
\end{aligned}
$$